# Need MySQL query to sum and avrage

Tags: mysql

I have duplicate rows in table, i want sum of quantity of duplicate row and average of purchase rate of duplicate rows, let me explain you by example.

Please give me mysql query to acheive desired output.

```
Problem Table
===================================================
POID    itemid      quantity       purchaserate
1       1           100             100
2       2           100             100
3       3           100             100
4       1           80              200
5       1           40              150
6       3           100             400 
====================================================

Desired output
===================================================
itemid      totalquantity   avgpurchaserate
1           220             145.45
2           100             100
3           200             250
===================================================
```

Tried below query

```
select itemid, sum(quantity), avg(purchaserate)
from test 
group by itemid

Output

itemid |sum(quantity) | avg(purchaserate)
1      |    220       |     150          
2      |    100       |     100
3      |    200       |     250
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: how does your query look like? which part is not working?

Comment: I have tried this >>>>   select itemid, sum(quantity), avg(purchaserate)
from test 
group by itemid

Comment: IT is not giving me correct output, as per my manual calculation.

Comment: So, you're looking for the` SUM(x)/SUM(x*y)`?? That seems fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation function as  sum and  avg and group by the column you need. In your case `itemid`

```
select itemid, sum(quantity) avg(purchaserate)
from my_table 
group by itemid
```

Comment: It is not wokring, because avg(purchaserate) is giving me avg of purchase rate, for example 1 purchase rate is 100 and second purchase rate is 200 then it will give me avg 150. But it is not considering quantity. If quantity for 100 purchase rate is 10 and quantity for 200 purchase rate is 50  then total quantity will be  60 and average purchase rate will be (1000+10000)/60 = 183.33

Comment: Of this calculation you  have mentioned  nothing in your question  .. how we can imagine this ????? ..  Anyway   your avg(purchaserate)  is the sum(quantity) /sum(purchaserate) ??  othrewise you should explain a lot better your questions ..